# How to execute a command on everyone except me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For a game I have been making, I want to (before I use `@p`) make the `/execute` command find everybody else except me. I tried:

```
/execute @a[type=!Player,name=username] /myCommand
```

But it doesn't work! Can anybody help?

Note: [username] is to be replaced with the user's Minecraft name.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use the NOT operator with the `name` parameter:

```
/execute @a[name=!username] ~ ~ ~ /say Test
```

As well, the `type` parameter is not used with the `@a` selector.